# how to capture the output that a function prints to the terminal in typescript/node

Tags: node.js, typescript, stdout, stderr

I am working with a typescript/node.js codebase, where there is a function that is called normally:

```
func('param1', 'param2', param3')
```

This function does not have a return value but it will print different kinds of output to the terminal when the code is run - this output might be normal `console.log` statements or an error of some sort. I want to be able to capture whatever the function print out into a variable for use later on - does anyone know how to capture what the function outputs into a variable? (so I can use it in if statments later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function use `console.log` to output the values, you can override it as:

```js
console.lg = console.log;

console.log = function(arg)
{
    console.lg(arg);
    global.myOutput = arg;
};
```

Then call your function and after that, check the value of global.myOutput.
Also, you can pass all this logic into an object:

```js
const logCapture = {
 output: null,
 enable() {
  console.lg = console.log;
  const that = this;

  console.log = function(arg) {
    console.lg(arg);
    that.output = arg;
   };
 },
 getOutput() {
  return this.output;
 },
 disable() {
  console.log = console.lg;
  console.lg = undefined;
 }
}
```

And use it:

```js
logCapture.enable();
callToFunction(...);
let myVar = logCapture.getOutput();
logCapture.disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be rather creating a wrapper function which will take care of printing to console and update a global variable.

```
let log = function(msg){
  console.log(msg);
  outputLog += msg + "\n";
}
```

Where ever you want to call the console.log, use log() instead